# Vlc metadata, save audio

Tags: sound, video, vlc

I have been trying to do a lot of things today, I am trying to play a network stream in VLC  and I know it is an option that will write the transcended stream into a file and save it from my nas server, for instance to my PC, or youtube, etc...

I want to do it via command line and I am doing it like this:

vlc 'https:link'
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:file{mux=mp3,dst=/home/alex/Desktop/vlc_test/a,no-overwrite} :no-sout-all :sout-keep

It is not working, I just want to save the audio, the rest I can deal with, but the saving part is the one that is so annoying, or I need to see it in the same time that is running. I would prefer to save it because I would be able to do multiple analytics based on that.

Thank you!